# ¿Por qué la interfaz no se visualiza en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy creando una interfaz con puro código (sin NetBeans u otro IDE), tengo el siguiente código:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Window extends JFrame
{
    public Window()
    {
        super();
        configureWindow();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void configureWindow()
    {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(650,500);
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        String opciones[] = {"Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo"};
        JList figura = new JList(opciones);

        JRadioButton mover = new JRadioButton();
        JRadioButton cambiarTam = new JRadioButton();
        JRadioButton rotar = new JRadioButton();

        figura.setBounds(10, 10, 25, 5);
        mover.setBounds(45, 10, 20, 5);
        mover.setText("Mover");
        cambiarTam.setBounds(75,10, 25, 5);
        cambiarTam.setText("Cambiar Tamaño");
        rotar.setBounds(110, 10, 25, 5);
        rotar.setText("Rotar");

        this.add(figura);
        this.add(mover);
        this.add(cambiarTam);
        this.add(rotar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Window ventana = new Window();
                ventana.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Al momento de poner en la consola **`javac NombredelArchivo.java`**, no me dice ningún error, pero tampoco me muestra la interfaz y después de un corto tiempo termina la instrucción en la consola.

Estoy usando Ubuntu 17.10, con OpenJDK 8, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Ejecuta: `javac file.java -Xlint` para que te muestre los errores de tu codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero: te recomiendo cambiar el nombre a la clase, Window es un componente AWT para evitar confusiones.

Segundo: para que el contenido se muestre dentro del frame, no debes agregarlo directamente en el, sino en el panel de contenido (`this.getContentPane()`). Por lo que al agregar los componentes tendrías algo así:

```
    this.getContentPane().add(figura);
    this.getContentPane().add(mover);
    this.getContentPane().add(cambiarTam);
    this.getContentPane().add(rotar);
```

Tercero: Te recomiendo que estudies y uses `Layout`s para definir la forma en que se mostrarán y organizarán los componentes en la pantalla en vez de asignar la posición y tamaño de cada componente de forma individual (eliminar `setBounds(x, y, ancho, alto)` y usar un `Layout`).

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos, soy novato en esto de GUI's con java, aunque no me respondió la pregunta me sirvió de guía para corregirlo. Ya encontré la manera de ejecutar las interfaces a través del terminal, primero debemos compilarla con **javac Nombredelarchivo.java**, depués de compilar ahí mismo en la carpeta del archivo se pone **java Nombredelaclase**.

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo usar para JFrame que van a ser paneles principales el método
`setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h))` porque el `setSize(w,h)` no hacia efecto alguno. Sería algo como esto:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650,500));
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo que también debes recordar que además de crear el JFrame debes hacer algo

//Ejemplo de referencia

```
JFrame miGui = new JFrame();
       miGui.setSize(w, h);
       miGui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h))
       miGui.setVisible(true);
       miGui.pack();
```